# como solucionar que VSCode me cambie la ubicación de las líneas de codigo

Tags: vscode

Estoy escribiendo un código que debe tener cierto orden; sin embargo, VSC me cambia la ubicación de la línea de código, porque cree que debería ir en otro lugar.
Escribo `from . import inicial` en la última línea

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y automáticamente me lo pasa a la primera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay un formateador que te está agrupando los imports al principio del código, que es lo más correcto. ¿Qué [formateador](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting) estás usando para python en vscode? (sobre los [reordenadores de imports en vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_sort-imports)) Y lo más importante, ¿cuál es la finalidad de "sobreescribir" `inicial` para que importe el orden?

Comment: Efectivamente, el formateador estaba haciendo eso, Intellisense, lo deshabilité y me los dejaba ordenar como quería,  `inicial` si no está después del blueprint, no funciona